# Apex method signature change does not reflect

Tags: apex, illuminatedcloud

I have an apex method for eg:

```
public static Boolean doSomething(String a, String b, String c) {}
```

When I update this method to

```
public static Boolean doSomething(String a, String b, String c, String d) {}
```

and I use it in Lightning

```
var x = component.get('c.doSomething');
x.setParams({
    a: '1', b:'2', c:'3', d:'4'
});
$A.enqueueAction(x);
```

it should send params `a,b,c,d`.

sometimes, it does not get recompiled and only sends params `a,b,c`.

sometimes, renaming this method works, but sometimes I have to create a class to get the change in.

Update:
1. The code is updated from the first method to second method
2. No errors
3. It does not see the new method signature update

Comment: Are these the exact method signatures (ie, 4 strings)? If not, what are the types used by the method? Do both methods exist at the same time in the class? Is any error given when the wrong method is called?

Comment: updated to reflect your questions

Comment: So it calls the method with three signatures instead of four? If you were to change the return of the functionality, does it call the old behavior instead of the new? If it does, it sounds like excessive caching causing problems for you.

Comment: the method with 3 parameters don't exists in the code anymore, but that's what's called. I tried what you said, to change the return value. Still did not trigger a proper recompile

Comment: Yeah, sounds like its accessing a cached class which hasn't been updated yet. [This is an old youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc5FrviQqO8) which goes into detail about how apex caching works. It doesn't cover lightning, but might at least help you understand whats going on behind the scenes. Changing the return was more to test if the parameters were being messed up somehow, or if a old function was being called. Only other thing I can think of is that something in your build process or IDE isn't deploying properly ..

Comment: This worked though. I used the DeveloperConsole to add a new method with the same signature, that was callable correctly. Then removed it and went back to original signature and was called correctly.
Initial code was deployed using IlluminatedCloud, so tagging it here.

Comment: I assume this is a typo *var x = component.get('c:doSomething');*. However if not, then you are not really calling the aura method, it should be *var x = component.get('c.doSomething');* (not : but .). Also you may like to check how are you deploying it. E.g., if you make any changes from developer console, it's real time updated and you can see the changes.

Comment: @Jayant: it was typo. fixed

Comment: I want to re-open this... I'm doing code changes from DeveloperConsole and definitely there's a problem. An exiting method if name is changed, it does not reflect. Also adding a parameter, changing return value does not tickle it.

Comment: More info... Definitely could not make it update during the same time frame. After waiting a few minutes I inserted a System.debug() message and it seemed to have picked it up. After that removed the message immediately and that reflected too. Not sure if this can be consistently used to tickle the cache.